# for which values of $\lambda$ $f(X,Y)$ defines an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$f(X,Y) = x_1y_1+6x_2y_2+3x_3y_3+2x_1y_2+2x_2y_1+3\lambda x_1y_3+3\lambda x_3y_1$.

I can write $f$ this way : $f(X,Y) =X^TAY= X^T \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3\lambda\\
        2 & 6 & 0\\
        3\lambda & 0 & 3\\
        \end{bmatrix} Y$

which means I can say that $f$ is a symmetric bilinear form

also since $1>0$, $\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 2\\
        2 & 6\\
        \end{vmatrix} = 2 >0 $

therefore $A$ is postive-definite if $\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3\lambda\\
        2 & 6 & 0\\
        3\lambda & 0 & 3\\
        \end{vmatrix} >0$, right ?

$$\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3\lambda\\
        2 & 6 & 0\\
        3\lambda & 0 & 3\\
        \end{vmatrix} >0\Leftrightarrow -54\lambda +6 > 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda <1/9$$
in conclusion $f$ defines an inner product iff $\lambda \in (-\infty,1/9)$.

I'm not 100% sure though I'm still new to inner product spaces and would like someone to confirm if I'm doing it right. thanks!

Comment: This seems reasonable to me.

Comment: seems absolutely right

Comment: Shouldn’t your expression for the determinant have $\lambda^2$ instead of $\lambda$?

Comment: @amd yes that's right thanks for noticing.

Comment: That’ll change your answer a bit :)